# Process result from places search google.api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

So i am currently working on a webapp where i am going to have to forge my own queryString to search for locations. I found out about the **Place Search** function in the google places api. However i dont really seem to understand how i am to process the data that i retrieve from the Query.

```
 var theUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=myHiddenKey";

   $.get(theUrl, function(data, status){
    ...I dont seem to get any results here and I know by 
     definition that there are matches... 
     cause if you run the same query in the searchbar of the browser you get all the matches
   });
```

If I wanted lets say get all of the names and locations of these spots how would I go about?

Help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I get an error running that request from javascript: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.`

If you want to use the Places API from javascript, use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)